# How to change a symfony project from mvc to client-server architecture?

Tags: php, client-server, symfony4

I recently started learning PHP and Symfony 4 and I developed an app. Now my next task is to change the architecture of the project, from MVC to client-server. More exactly, I need to have my templates and controllers in an application and the business logic in another application. Any ideas how I can do this? I can't even figure out how to run 2 different symfony projects simultaneously.

Comment: For example with two different git-repositories and private packages or with Symfony bundles.

Answer (score 0):

A client-server application is an application base on a communication model call `client-server`: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

MVC is a way to develop and structure application: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

But i understand your needs. You want to keep a symfony app but you also want to put all the logic view and front end features into a separate app (like React or Vue)

Your Symfony App will still use MVC pattern, just you'll replace what the controller give to the view.

The best way is to turn the Symfony App into API with normalize view data like JSON or XML. Those data will feed your front app.

To achieve this you can use this bundle, which turn your model layers into API: [API Platform](https://api-platform.com/)